# Which algorithm for predicting the next word(s) based on previous words, given a sentence?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing

I want to input some words, and out comes the next word(s). Neural nets are really hot at the moment, and I'm afraid of throwing a neural net at something, when one is not really needed. Or... maybe it is needed?

My current options are:

- Predict next word(s) using N-grams
- Predict next word(s) using a neural net

There are quite a number of Github repositories that does this using neural nets, and a few that does it with N-grams. Are there any clear advantages to choosing the neural net approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use anything you like.  Right now neural networks are the state of the art: they produce the best predictions.  But you could also use HMMs, or n-grams, or other methods; they just will be lower quality than a state-of-the-art neural network.